# Problem with manim, manimlib file missing

Tags: python, manim

I installed manim and it succesfuly renders videos that dont use LaTeX. When I try rendering LaTeX i get this error:

```
latex error converting to dvi.
```

Ive seen some people recommending to run:

```
latex tex_template.tex
```

In the manimlib file, however I dont have such file which I suspect is causing the problem. What might be the reason Im missing this file and how could i get it?

I tried searching for it through all the files and I couldnt find it, after uninstallling and installing I still could not find it.

Comment: Run it in verbose mode. Extract a [mcve]. Check the bugtracker. If that's a supported operation and doesn't work, file a bug ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You have Tex_Template.tex, but your path is wrong to look at
https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/623#issuecomment-515730122

this could also be why you are getting latex error converting to dvi. also...

Comment: I changed the Path variable and it didnt change anything. Is that the fix you meant?

Comment: yea, change the path and restart the computer... this should solve the issue at hand.

Comment: After restarting the computer it still didn't work.

Comment: try running a force update using the command "tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed"